# Php code does not execute after return:false;

Tags: php

The Php code below (last on page) checks if the user has pressed the "Reply" button, and then does stuff. All OK, but if in the huge script that continues below at some point I trigger a javascript alert from Php, which returns false, it does absolutely nothing... How can I make Php remember and execute this part

```
if (cmtx_setting('show_reply')) { //if reply field is enabled
        $cmtx_reply_id = trim($_POST['cmtx_reply_id']); //remove any space at beginning and end
        cmtx_is_injected($cmtx_reply_id); //check for injection attempt
        cmtx_validate_reply($cmtx_reply_id, $cmtx_page_id); //validate reply
        $cmtx_reply_to = cmtx_sanitize($cmtx_reply_id, true, true); //sanitize reply
    }
```

even if at some point in the script I have `return false;` ?

**Full snippet of code:**

```
/* Reply To */
    if (!isset($_POST['cmtx_reply_id'])) { //if reply ID not submitted
        $_POST['cmtx_reply_id'] = 0; //set it with a zero value
    }
    if (cmtx_setting('show_reply')) { //if reply field is enabled
        $cmtx_reply_id = trim($_POST['cmtx_reply_id']); //remove any space at beginning and end
        cmtx_is_injected($cmtx_reply_id); //check for injection attempt
        cmtx_validate_reply($cmtx_reply_id, $cmtx_page_id); //validate reply
        $cmtx_reply_to = cmtx_sanitize($cmtx_reply_id, true, true); //sanitize reply
    } else {
        $cmtx_reply_to = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `return false;` acts as a killer - it `exists;` the script run. For example;

```
<?php

echo "Hello";
return false;
echo "World";
```

https://eval.in/201188

The output is just: `Hello`

From reading [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)

> [...] **return also ends the execution of** an eval() statement or **script file**. If called from the global scope, then **execution of the current script file is ended**

Comment: Sorry for that, typo (too much CSS on my mind), edited the post.

Comment: But the code I entered is placed before the first return false; in my file. This is what I don't understand...

Comment: It does, but then form validation also stops (the form is submitted, but even if empty).